# Is it possible to use more than one splash page for app development using Phonegap? If not, is there any alternative way to do so?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, phonegap-build

I am creating an app using Phonegap. There is a requirement where I have to use three splash pages automatically swiping from right to left until the page loads.

I have already added a splash screen in config.xml and it is showing also. But I need to load three splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use multiple images as a splash screen and also can not use gif image

but i think here is your solution http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-quick-tip-creating-frame-animations--mobile-15044

Comment: Thank you Akshay, but is it possible to change the spinner loader into a progress bar on splash screen until the index page loads?